# Request Timed Out while pinging google domain with ping google.com -t

Tags: internet, cmd.exe, ping, packet-loss

I have a problem with my internet connection which I found on 2 different lines not only 1.

When I play an online game I have a sudden 75% packet loss on the net graph, it happens randomly even though my internet speed is good and router lights "ADSL and Internet" are stable.

I dug into this and reached the point where I pinged the Google servers in the CMD with this command `Ping google.com -t` to see my ping and receiving replies coming from the Google domain.

I found that "Request timed out" appears randomly between the replies which translates in game to 75% packet loss and each "request timed out" gives me 75% packet loss for like 3-5 seconds and it happens frequently and it never stops during the whole day and night.

My ping in Egypt is high because we are far from EU servers, the best I can get is 60ms ping, so don't mind the ping. My problem is the request timed out which is translating into packet loss.

I contacted my ISP many times but they don't admit there is a problem and I can't find anyone who is understanding enough to help me.

Here is a screenshot to show you what i mean

[image]

Comment: Are you using your ISPs default DNS or Google's DNS? Maybe try modifying DNS to hold values  `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` This can be done by Control Panel > Networking and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings > Right click on your ethernet adapter and choose Properties. Double click on IPV4 and then edit the bottom 2 DNS values. This may help. Otherwise, are you using a Killer network driver by chance?

Comment: Yes sir i used my ISP dns and google dns too also cloud flare one and nothing is working , and nope im using the right network driver for me also something to clear is that some of my friends are having the same issue..

Comment: I think this too broad for us to be able answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could be late. Nevertheless, you can check the physical connection. Make sure your switch/router is not on a hot place- has proper ventilation.secondly, are you on fiber?if yes, then try replacing electrical/optical SFP. Try rebooting the media converters as well if any.

I work with an ISP and we encounter this on a day to day basis. In most cases, either there's a degradation of service from ISP, or your physical connection requires to be checked out.

Comment: I had the same effect for several weeks (getting worse and worse). Worked much better for ~ 1 hour after rebooting the router. Then it died... The new router has none of those "outages".